# Why the link not giving data outside its webapplication

Tags: python, websocket, python-requests

When I am inspecting the website of sydenypogomaphttps://sydneypogomap.com it's showing the desired result in its API call which looks like =[image]

but when I am calling the API in the browser or in vs code using requests it returns an empty byte array.
Link of the api is https://sydneypogomap.com/query2.php?mons=16&time=1651570475802&since=1651570405

Comment: Maybe there is some sort of authentication cookie that is required to authorize the request?

Answer (score 0):

In the above question, I made a major mistake as I was new to web scraping. This issue is due to a protocol known as cors which is used as a security measure to insure that the requests are made through the original site page... So to over this small issue we pass headers with API requests whose syntax is like:

```
headers={
'Host': 'www.luisaviaroma.com',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/.........',
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'DNT': '1',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1'
}
#now we have to pass it like this:
request.get("https://www.anywebsite.com",headers=headers)
```

we can get headers for any website API by the network in the inspector by using the edit and resend option where we can see raw headers like this image>>>

[image: Example of how raw headers look]